# Merge local SSH keys to work simultaneously

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

I have been using SSH alot. I find myself creating new keys when something fails, like for `git`, then I lose communication to my other servers. I know going forward there should only be one set of locally generated keys, but for now, I need to merge the many `/.ssh` backups I've made so they can all be used simultaneously. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible to list many keys in your `~/.ssh/config`.  Or you can add many keys to an [SSH agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent).

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/zoredache_20101108.id_rsa
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/zoredache_20100211.id_rsa
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/zoredache_20080514_id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ~/.ssh/config file try:

> ```
> Host A
>     IdentityFIle ~/.ssh/for-host-a.id
>
> Host B
>     IdentityFIle ~/.ssh/for-host-b.id
>
> Host C
>     IdentityFIle ~/.ssh/for-host-c.id
> ```

A session setup only allows 3 authentication attemps before the connection is dropped. Think of that as a 3 ID file limit. With the above, you can ssh to host A and it will use just that ID file. ssh to host B and it uses a different one, and so on.